# Deduce member function override from arguments

Tags: c++

In C++, is there a way of deducing the correct member function override based on the input arguments to the function?

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct Test {
    int foo(int, char) { return 0; }
    int foo(char) { return 1; }
};

template <typename R, class C, typename... Args>
auto invoke(R (C::*f)(Args...), C * c, Args&&... args) {
    return (c->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main(int, char *[]) {
    Test t;
    return invoke(&Test::foo, &t, 1, 'a');
}
```

I want the compiler to choose the overload `int foo(int, char)` based on the input arguments being `(1, 'a')` but deduction fails:

```cpp
review.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
review.cpp:15:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘invoke(<unresolved overloaded function type>, Test*, int, char)’
   15 |     return invoke(&Test::foo, &t, 1, 'a');
      |            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
review.cpp:9:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class R, class C, class ... Args> auto invoke(R (C::*)(Args ...), C*, Args&& ...)’
    9 | auto invoke(R (C::*f)(Args...), C * c, Args&&... args) {
      |      ^~~~~~
review.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
review.cpp:15:18: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘R’
   15 |     return invoke(&Test::foo, &t, 1, 'a');
      |            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Interestingly, this works if I specify the return type using `invoke<int>([...])` but I don't want to have to specify the return type because my real code has different return types from different functions that are to be invoked...

Using GCC 12.2.

Comment: I'd pass a lambda instead of the member pointer. Otherwise I don't see a good solution, except perhaps a macro that uses `decltype` to determine the return type.

Comment: Do you mean `invoke([&] { return t.foo(1, 'a'); });`

Comment: Yes. Or, a templated lambda, like `[&](auto &&... a) -> decltype(auto) {return t.foo(decltype(a)(a)...);}`, with args passed separately.

Comment: That's always an option. I just thought this would be prettier if I could get it to work.

Comment: It seems [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) succeeds to catch the return type. Maybe you could take a look at it and how it's done.

Comment: You can generate the lambda with a macro (then you can get even more correctness by adding `noexcept` and a return type without `auto` that's SFINAE-friendly), I've seen a few people do it. But if `std::invoke` works, as the other commenter says, you can just use it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `std::invoke` [fails](https://godbolt.org/z/hWafhnrcY) to do the job, it is fundamentally impossible to achieve what OP wants w/o macro, simply because `&Class::member` is ill-formed if `member` is overloaded.

Comment: @Dmitry It's not ill-formed if it's immediately converted to a specific member-pointer type, as OP observed when calling `invoke<int>(...)`. But getting this conversion to happen automatically in all cases is probably not feasible, yes.

Comment: @Fareanor `std::invoke` wouldn't be able to do it either afaik. It would have to be something like `std::invoke(static_cast<int(Test::*)(int,char)>(&Test::foo), &t, 1, 'a');` just like in OPs code.

Comment: Jeez... I don't think I've gotten as many ICEs from gcc ever before as when trying to figure this one out :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might put member function parameter in non-deducing context, and set them from passed argument.

Caveat is that arguments should match. so forwarding reference is problematic...

Moreover, return type cannot be deduced by clang and gcc though :/.

```
#include <utility>

struct Test {
    int foo(int, char) { return 0; }
    int foo(char) { return 1; }
};

template <typename R, class C, typename... Args>
auto invoke(R (C::*f)(std::type_identity_t<Args>...), C* c, Args... args) {
    return (c->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    Test t;
    return invoke<int>(&Test::foo, &t, 1, 'a'); // <int> required for non-msvc
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6qz9bKT93)

Alternative to handle overload set is to wrap in a functor (typically a lamba):

```
#include <utility>

struct Test {
    int foo(int, char) { return 0; }
    int foo(char) { return 1; }
};

template <typename F, typename C, typename... Args>
auto invoke(F f, C* c, Args... args) {
    return f(c, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    Test t;
    return invoke([](auto* c, auto&&... args){ return c->foo(args...); }, &t, 1, 'a');
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sdjcjW1xz)